# TextBox value not updating before later actions

Tags: c#

I have created a textbox on my form to let the user know the status of the procedure they have initiated.  The first value to be displayed in this tb is "Calculating report...".  This field is updated 3 times total during the process, but only the final value is ultimately visible.

```
    private void bRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tRunTime.Text = "Calculating report...";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
        conn.Open();

        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        using (conn)
        {
            try
            {
                //my code...                
            }
            catch (Exception r)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + r, "Report Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            tRunTime.Text = "Calculation complete.  Exporting to Excel...";

            string sqlReport = "my sql string";

            //Populate dataset
            SqlDataAdapter adapterReport = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlReport, conn);

            DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
            dsReport.Tables.Add(sqlReport);
            adapterReport.Fill(dsReport, sqlReport);

            ExportDataSetToExcel(sqlReport); // Local custom process that I use on many forms.  It works perfectly.

            Process.Start(@"path to temp file");
        }

        conn.Close();

        stopWatch.Stop();

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);

        tRunTime.Text = "Report run time: " + elapsedTime;

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Everything here works perfectly, except the first two status stages ("Calculating report..." and "Calculation complete.  Exporting to Excel...") never actually appear on the form.

I am somewhat new to C#, so if you see other improvements to me code, I am all ears as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is because the UI is single threaded. When an event is fired, nothing happen in the UI until the control is given back to the framework at the end of the called method. If you want to have the UI respond while it is calculating, you might want to look into a [`BackgroundWorker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem:

The UI is single threaded therefore causing it not to respond completely during a long running task.

### The Solution:

Try using a `BackgroundWorker` or another `Thread` with delegates. Both should allow for multi threading with access to the UI.

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into this.  Appreciate it!

Comment: @kevin, No problem, and please if this solves your issue please mark as correct solution for others.